# Not getting the values from some fields of the fieldset

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I am trying to get the values from a field set which is containg name, mobile number, email address and all those. Here is my field set code:

```
 {
                    xtype : 'fieldset',
                    docked : 'top',
                    id: 'signuptextfield',
                    margin : '10 0 0 0',
                    width : 600,
                    scrollable: true,
                    height : 180,

                    items : [ {
                        xtype : 'textfield',
                        id : 'consumername',
                        style : 'font: Droid Sans',
                        label : 'Consumer Name',
                        labelWidth : '30%'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'numberfield',
                        id : 'mobilenum',
                        style : 'font: Droid Sans',
                        label : 'Mobile',
                        labelWidth : '30%'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'emailfield',
                        id : 'email',
                        label : 'Customer Email id',
                        labelWidth : '30%',
                        placeHolder : 'email@example.com'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'textareafield',
                        id : 'adressfield',
                        style : 'font: Droid Sans',
                        label : 'Address',
                        labelWidth : '30%'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'textfield',
                        id : 'areafield',
                        style : 'font: Droid Sans',
                        label : 'Area/Location',
                        labelWidth : '30%'
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'selectfield',
                        label : 'City',
                        labelWidth : '30%',
                        options : [ {
                            text : 'Bangalore',
                            value : 'first'
                        }, {
                            text : 'Delhi',
                            value : 'second'
                        }, {
                            text : 'Mumbai',
                            value : 'third'
                        } ]
                    }, {
                        xtype : 'numberfield',
                        id : 'pinfield',
                        style : 'font: Droid Sans',
                        label : 'Pincode*',
                        labelWidth : '30%'
                    }, ]
                }, {
                    xtype : 'button',
                    height : 40,
                    id : 'submitbtn',
                    margin : '10 0 0 0',
                    ui : 'orange',
                    width : 220,
                    text : 'Submit'
                }
```

Now in the submit button click, i am trying to get this values:
First, i tried with the below code:

```
var consumerName = Ext.getCmp('signuptextfield').getValues();
```

But it is giving error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getValues' at file:///android_asset/www/app/controller/MyController.js:164
```

Then i tried with the below code:

```
onSubmitButtonTap : function(button, e, options) {
function storeCustomerDetails(tx)
    {
        var consumerName = Ext.getCmp('consumername').getValue();
        var consumerMobNo = Ext.getCmp('mobilenum').getValue();
        var consumerEmail = Ext.getCmp('email').getValue();
        var consumerAddress = Ext.getCmp('adressfield').getValue();
        var consumerArea = Ext.getCmp('areafield').getValue();
        console.log("the datas are:"+consumerName);
        console.log("the datas are:"+consumerMobNo);
        console.log("the datas are:"+consumerEmail);
        console.log("the datas are:"+consumerAddress);
        console.log("the datas are:"+consumerArea);
   }
```

But i am able to get only the Consumer name and mobile number. Other fields it is returning null..I do not know where is the exact problem..

Help needed..

Comment: Is it just me, or are there fictional xtypes for the fields which you can't get stuff for?

Comment: If i am putting my field set inside a form panel, i am able to access the value. In that way i resolved the problem. But if there is no fieldset in my screen and am trying to get the values of a text box using getCmp, i am not getting the value of the text box..